# Проблемы с Intent - ActivityNotFoundException при запуске активити

Tags: java, android

Есть код main класса, в котором две кнопки и два обработчика:

```
public void goToSettings(View v) {
    Intent relationMainToSettings = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(relationMainToSettings);
}

public void goToMyMap(View v){
    Intent relationMainToMap = new Intent(this, MapScreen.class);
    startActivity(relationMainToMap);
}
```

Первый, работает корректно. Второй все время вылетает с ошибкой:

> 23132-23132/ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3067)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14172)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3062)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14172)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {ua.repikserj.CarpatianWays/ua.repikserj.CarpathianWays.MapScreen};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1514)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1390)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3234)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3341)
>               at ua.repikserj.CarpathianWays.MainActivityCW.goToMyMap(MainActivityCW.java:62)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3062)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14172)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Ошибка на строке `startActivity(relationMainToMap);`

Вот код MapScreen:

```
public class MapScreen extends Activity {

    ListView mListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);

        String[] exampleItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.example_items);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuListView);
        Log.d("List","OKOKOK");
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exampleItems));
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MapScreen.this, KyivMap.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MapScreen.this, KyivMap.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Все вроде как обычно делаю, не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Полный лог покажите

Comment: Полный лог добавил

Comment: Код манифеста покажите.

Comment: По-любому в манифесте не декларирована

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `Activity` ваша `MapScreen`, видимо, не объявлена в манифесте.

В пункте `activity` манифеста указывайте полный путь до класса вашего `Activity`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.android.myApp.blabla.MapScreen">
</activity>
```

Возможно у вас там:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MapScreen">
</activity>
```

В таком случае он будет пытаться найти в корневом пакете вашу `Activity`. Если она у вас в другом пакете, то указывайте полный путь в манифесте.

Comment: Точно, так и есть. Спасибо!

Comment: Я был на 5 секунд быстрее(((((

Comment: @SerjR, ваш уровень репутации теперь позволяет помимо отмечания "верным" ещё и голосовать за хорошие вопросы/ответы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `отвечен 19 минут` назад vs `отвечен 9 минут назад` :P

Comment: @Suvitruf, я ответил на 9 секунд раньше, чем вы внесли правку, приведя ответ в текущий вид. Точные даты вашей правки / моего ответа: 17:59:25vs19:59:16 =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб просто я поподробнее старался расписать )

Comment: @Suvitruf, но я хотя бы нам по 10 репы выпросил) И вам плюссанул. P.S. голосуйте за меня на выборах)))))))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб докину ещё )

Comment: @Suvitruf, спс) Давайте всегда друг друга лайкать)))

Answer (score 3):

Судя по логам проблема может быть в манифесте.

Либо активити MapScreen не добавлена в манифест или там не верно указан полный путь к классу.